# How can I tell which Javascript module created an element/table on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I started working at a place that has a huge webpage app built already.  I have been hired to do front-end testing with Selenium, but I'm curious to see the inner workings of the app.  My question is, with Chrome dev tools or something similar, how can I tell what Javascript module created an element / table / form that I am seeing on the page?  I can 'inspect element' and look at the DOM, but I want to know which .js file to dig into to to see how the element was built.

In essence, in Chrome dev tools, how do I bridge the gap between the DOM inspector and the Source files that built the DOM.

Comment: You hardly can. That would require the browser to keep track of every single piece of code which ever touched a specific element, which is potentially thousands of lines of code all over, which sounds like a ginormous resource drain.

Comment: First thought: unlikely it is possible. How to prove it? No idea...

Comment: Search for the elems id in js. They must be assigned somewhere

Answer (score 2):

I made a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fromjs/hjkhdaoomfphjmffaklelpmkllfbjjfd) that let's you inspect a page and see the relevant JavaScript code for each DOM element. It's still very flaky, but might be worth giving it a try.

It's based in part on the approach Pranay has suggested.

[image]

Comment: Update the link, please.

Answer (score 1):

creating DOM elements can be done by setting the innerHTML of any DOM element or calling appendChild method. So proxy these two using JavaScript [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). To know the location you can chrome console method console.trace();

Ex:

Suppose you have this HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

your proxy should be like this

```
var divEl = document.querySelector('div');

divEl.appendChild = new Proxy(divEl.appendChild, {
  apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    console.trace();
    target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList);
  }
});
```

some where in the code if following code is executed

```
var pEl = document.createElement('p');
divEl.appendChild(pEl);
```

you can see from where it is called in the console.

Comment: Proxy must be done before javascript on the page gets executed to do so you can put a debug point at the first line of the code and execute your proxy in console. OR you can you chrome extensions like tampermonkey

Comment: When you proxy something, and use trace, won't it point to the location of the proxy? How do you figure out what triggered the proxy? Could you post a simple implementation? BTW, You can [edit] your post to add more info rather than adding comments

Comment: Another pain point is that libraries like jQuery has wrappers for these methods. How do you make a proxy that points to the actual code rather than such wrappers?

Comment: Why a proxy? Can't you just assign the custom function?

Comment: @T J Yea you are correct. To get better result proxy must be done for a particular element's function or property.

Comment: And trace even though it points to proxy. it gets to proxy from the location where the point it is actually called. As we have the trace we can easily figure out its location