# Google Chrome Console set breakpoint on HTML element additions

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way I can set a breakpoint on new HTML element additions after the page has loaded?

I have a plugin that renders a popup (on click event) to the page and there is a specific tag attribute that is changing ONLY after I click on the button to render the popup -- I need to set a breakpoint on that tag when the attribute changes

I tried using "break on->subtree modifications" but there is so much code that is generated by the plugin and I would like to know if there's any way to break on that specific tag

I tried setting "break on->attribute modifications" after I popup is rendered - but when I close the popup and click to open the popup again,  the breakpoint is gone and is not saved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put a breakpoint on some js that is attached to the button (if any)? And then just next, next, next.. until you get to the attribute change? You should be able to swap to the element view and watch it after breaking.

Comment: good idea.  I suppose I can put "debugger" when I see the attr changing.  I wanted a more elegant approach where when the dev tools sees #someclass attr changes break the code immediately.

Comment: Yeah, chrome can be a pain. But it's nice cause it's there... Ya know? Anyway that's what I'd do in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

"break on->subtree modifications" should work. Looks like you are having some problem with that. If you are ok with spending some time this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573121/how-can-i-tell-which-javascript-module-created-an-element-table-on-a-webpage/41573351#41573351) might help you

Answer (score 0):

## Subtree Modification Breakpoints

[Subtree Modification Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom) are my go-to solution in situations like this. You mentioned that a lot of HTML gets changed. It may help to set the breakpoint on a more-specific node. For example:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Suppose the element that you want to inspect is a child of `<p>`. Rather than setting the breakpoint on the `<body>` or `<div>`, set it on the `<p>`. It'll only change when the children of the `<p>` change.

## Event Listener Breakpoints

If you want to break in the event listener code of the button that causes the change, you can set an [Event Listener Breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#event-listeners).
 I give an example of it in [What's New In DevTools (Chrome 63)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eyw_mwbABIQ&t=220), also.